# Sorted array to array consists of balanced BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have a problem solving a question:

Given a sorted array of integers! re-order the array (recursively) in which the new array will be as balanced binary search tree.

example:

- [1,2,3] -> [2,1,3]
- [1,2,3,4] -> [3,2,1,4]

Comment: What have you tried? I see no attempt here. Perhaps you should (re)read the learning material, because they wouldn't give a test problem like this without first teaching what you need to know to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do three things:

1. Build a normal binary tree, by adding all elements from the left to the right.
2. Rebalance the tree
3. Dump it back into an array

Comment: We are not allowed to use OOP (no such class BT)

Comment: You can use other programming paradigms (like Functional Programming)